# Disable websites' smooth scroll feature?

Tags: browser, scrolling

I hate that websites still have some sort of smooth scrolling feature despite it being disabled in my browser (Chrome flag disabled).

I think it's coming from javascript.
https://www.thegeekpub.com/ is one example site. I deleted the wheel event listener from the developer options, which works for that page, but I'd like something that disables such a 'feature' from any other site that has it.

Is there an addon or something to do this? A tampermonkey script, even?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35611393/992504
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("wheel",function (event) {
  // exception for ACE Editor, JS text editor used by sites like GitHub
  if (event.target.classList.contains('ace_content')) {
    return;
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks ChoGGi!

I made a bookmarklet (drag this to your bookmarks and click it when you want to remove smoothscroll):

[Disable SmoothScroll](http://javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.getElementsByTagName(%22body%22)%5B0%5D.addEventListener(%22wheel%22,function%20(event)%20%7Bif%20(event.target.classList.contains(%27ace_content%27))%20%7Breturn;%7Devent.stopPropagation();%7D,%20true);%7D)();)

If it doesn't work paste this code into a bookmark's URL field:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("wheel",function (event) {if (event.target.classList.contains('ace_content')) {return;}event.stopPropagation();}, true);})();
```

Here is a website to test:
https://hollandshielding.com/IP-Rating-Chart

Comment: ... and if even this doesn't work, make sure that what you've pasted into the URL field does retain the `javascript:` prefix, which modern browsers strip away, supposedly for security reasons.

Comment: @Ruslan Which browser is that. it does work in Chrome

Comment: In Chromium, when I copy & paste (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V) this snippet, I only get `(function...` pasted, without the prefix.

Comment: Strange I just tried it in Google Chrome which comes from Chromium. Try to edit the bookmark after it is created and paste the script. When I drag the link it gets blocked, but when I edit and paste the script it works. Also tested in Firefox - works (at least after edit). However I can't find a smooth scroll site to test it. Few sites I knew are smoothscrolling now don't. maybe browsers blocked that feature...

Comment: Ah, I didn't paste it into _bookmark_ field — just into the _address bar_

Comment: Yes, make a bookmark and paste it in url field